# Does JDK 8 supports JasperReports 6?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, java-8

I've been trying to get my report working for few days but still no luck. I have no idea if it's something wrong with the dependencies.

[I asked this question previously.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937750/a-xml-related-exception-occurred-while-compiling-the-jasperreport)

**Anyway i just want to know if anyone have used JasperReports 6 with JDK 8? after all i doubt if these are compatible.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [What version of JaspeReports has support for Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23315545/what-version-of-jaspereports-has-support-for-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out the issue after trying few days.
My report didn't work not due to an incompatibility issue. But because i haven't used

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, param, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

instead of

```
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, param);
```

Yes. JDK 8 is compatible with JasperReports 6.

JasperReports doesn't have enough community support i had to figure this out by my self. Anyway i suggest that JasperReports library should be much improved.

Answer (score 4):

Update your JDT

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Source : [How to Run JasperReport with Java 8](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/844403/how-run-jasperreports-java-8)