# Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Yes, before you mark this question as "possible duplicate of", please, I actualy tried diferent solutions of the list below:

1. Set compability mode like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910867/jaspersoft-studio-adding-uuid-when-data-adapter-is-changed-for-report).
   [image]
2. Use the latest version of Jasper Report (Im using the 6.3.1 version).
3. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458185/compilation-error-ireport-with-javaattribute-uuid-is-not-allowed-to-appear-i) someone says "you need to add the latest version of JR Libary", maybe I need more jar files in my project...

My project already have this jar files

[[image]]

What netbeans says when I call the report?

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 441; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'uuid' is not allowed to appear in element 'jasperReport'.
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:247)
>       at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:230)
>   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:218)

This is how I call the report now from JAVA:

```
public class Reportes{
private Administrador admin;

public Reportes() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    admin = new Administrador();
}

public JRViewer obtenerPaciente(String ced) throws JRException, FileNotFoundException{
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("assets/PerfilPaciente.jrxml");
    JRDesignQuery design = new JRDesignQuery();
    design.setText("SELECT * FROM Pacientes");
    JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load(is);
    jd.setQuery(design);
    parameters.put("Imagen", ClassLoader.getSystemResource("assets/perfil-azul.png").getPath());
    parameters.put("Cedula",ced);
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, admin.obtenerConexion());
    JRViewer jrv = new JRViewer(jp);             
    return jrv;
}
}
```

Where I call it

```
bbusca.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if(txtbusc.getText().length() != 0){
                try {
                    reporte.obtenerPaciente(txtbusc.getText()).setVisible(true);
                } catch (JRException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(BuscarPaciente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No has ingresado nada.");
            }
        }
    });
```

I dont know if is necesary put the jrxml code here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 4.5.0  -->
<!-- 2016-11-01T19:34:20 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PerfilPaciente" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="HospitalAccess"/>
    <parameter name="Cedula" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Cedula del paciente]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{Cedula}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Imagen" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Icono del reporte]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{Imagen}]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Pacientes WHERE Cedula=$P{Cedula}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Nombre" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Apellido" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Fecha_Nacimiento" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Cedula" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Sexo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Tipo_Sangre" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Direccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Telefono" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="145" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="-20" width="612" height="165" backcolor="#9CD7FF"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="20" width="265" height="40"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="25" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Perfil del paciente]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="10" y="60" width="265" height="22" forecolor="#7D3E00"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="100" width="612" height="30" backcolor="#DBF6FF"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="100" width="340" height="30" forecolor="#961212"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Hospital Salud]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="480" y="2" width="80" height="80"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{Imagen}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="437" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nombre:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Apellido:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nacimiento:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="220" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sexo:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="270" width="130" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tipo de sangre:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="320" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Dirección:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="170" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cédula:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="370" width="100" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Télefono:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="20" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Nombre}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="70" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Apellido}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="120" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Fecha_Nacimiento}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="170" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Cedula}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="220" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Sexo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="270" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Tipo_Sangre}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="320" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Direccion}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="370" width="260" height="30"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Telefono}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="144" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="612" height="144" backcolor="#9CD7FF"/>
            </rectangle>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I just cant understand whats going on here. :/

Comment: Which libraries are in classpath?

Comment: I put a screenshot of the libraries that have added so far ... a couple belong to JasperViewer and one (jasperreports 6.3.1) belongs to JasperLibrary. I saw in a video that when you download this package, you had to add everything that contained a folder named "lib" but in the  new version, I see that the folder is empty...(I added that I just mentioned). Others belong to UcanAccess. @AlexK

Comment: It is looks like a magic. You should check libraries loaded by application (with help of classloader)